# PintOS Installation in Bochs

Tags: c, linux, pintos

I am installing Pintos in Bochs for past several days. Everything compiled fine in the "threads" directory and I have also set all the paths fine. I have the kernel.lo and other files in the build directory.

The problem is with the last command I run:
pintos run alarm-multiple

This produces an error:
Unrecognized character \x16; marked by <-- HERE after   if ($<-- HERE near column 7 at /home/superboy/pintos/src/utils/pintos line 911.

The code at line 911 of the pintos script is:

```
# Calls setitimer to set a timeout, then execs what was passed to us.
sub exec_setitimer {
if (defined $timeout) {
if ($  ge 5.8.0) {
    eval "
          use Time::HiRes qw(setitimer ITIMER_VIRTUAL);
          setitimer (ITIMER_VIRTUAL, $timeout, 0);
        ";
} else {
    { exec ("setitimer-helper", $timeout, @_); };
    exit 1 if !$!{ENOENT};
    print STDERR "warning: setitimer-helper is not installed, so ",
      "CPU time limit will not be enforced\n";
}
}
exec (@_);
exit (1);
}
```

I am using Debian-9 Stretch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I repeated the same steps in ubuntu and it worked. Seems like pintos has problems running on Debian.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Pintos file inside the utils directory with vim, replace the characters "^V" by actually typing in the control characters. This should fix it.